# Alguem pode me ajudar com este exercicio?

Tags: c, array, funções, matriz, syntax-error

EXERCÍCIO:

Escreva uma função que retorne o número do time que está na liderança. A liderança é
determinada pelo time que tiver maior número de pontos ganhos. Se um ou mais times
tiverem o mesmo número de pontos, e usado o seguinte critério de desempate: número de
vitórias e saldo de gols, nesta ordem. Se, mesmo assim, dois ou mais times empataram,
deve-se retornar o número de um dos times líderes. A função deve receber como
parâmetros o número de times, n, e a tabela com os resultados, tab, e deve obedecer ao
seguinte protótipo:

int lider(int n, int tab[][6]);

```
#include <stdio.h>

int melhorsaldo(int n, int tab[][6]) {
    int l, i=0;
    for (l=1;l<n;l++) {
        if ((tab[l][4]-tab[l][5]) > (tab[i][4]-tab[i][5])) {
            i = l;
        }
    }
    return i;
};

int main() {
    int n, l, c, res;
    printf("Quantos times sao?\n ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int tab[n][6];
    printf("Digite os elementos da matriz\n");
    for(l=0; l<n; l++) {
        for(c=0; c<6; c++) {
             printf("[%d][%d]: ", l, c);
             scanf("%d", &tab[l][c]);
        }
    }
    res = melhorsaldo(n, tab);
    res++;
    printf("\nMelhor saldo de gols, time: %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem que verificar as condições em cascata. Você não definiu o que fazer quando ocorre empate em tudo, considerei o que aparece primeiro na tabela.

```
int melhorclassificado(int n, int tab[][6]) {
    int l, i=0;
    for (l=1; l<n; l++) {
        if (tab[l][0] > tab[i][0]) { /* l tem mais pontos */
            i = l; 
        }
        else {
            if (tab[l][0] == tab[i][0]) { /* empate em pontos */
                if (tab[l][1] > tab[i][1]) { /* l tem maior número de vitórias */
                    i = l;
                }
                else {
                    if (tab[l][1] == tab[i][1]) { /* empate em pontos e número de vitórias */
                        if ((tab[l][4]-tab[l][5]) > (tab[i][4]-tab[i][5])) { /* l tem melhor saldo de gols */
                            i = l;
                        }
                        else {
                            if ((tab[l][4]-tab[l][5]) == (tab[i][4]-tab[i][5])) { /* empate em pontos, número de vitórias e saldo de gols */
                                ; /* Considera o que apareceu primeiro, no caso i */
                            }
                            else {
                                ; /* empate em pontos, número de vitórias mas i tem melhor saldo de gols */
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        ; /* empate em pontos mas i tem mais vitórias */
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                ; /* i tem mais pontos */
            }
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```